# Spring Boot 3 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring

Я перевожу свой проект на Spring Boot 3. И получаю ошибку тестов в других классах, что не пробовал - не могу победить.

> java.jang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/DispatcherType

Все импорты в коде уже поменяны на jakarta.

```
 repositories {
     mavenCentral{
         url '********'
     }
 }

 group = '*****'
 sourceCompatibility = '17'

 apply from: 'gradle/sonar.gradle'

 dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    // OAuth 2.0 Resource Server support
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'

    // Lombok
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'`

    // Actuator
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    // Micrometer
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.10.6'
    // Logger
    implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.3'

    // Test
    testImplementation  'org`your text`.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.35.0'
    testImplementation 'org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.7.6'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
}


test {
   useJUnitPlatform()
   finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
```

Comment: Судя по логу что то требует javax, а в проекте только jakarta Можешь приложить полный лог?
А вообще выглядит на проблему с зависимостями